# iOS:Admob mediation with InMobi:No ads to show

Tags: ios, swift, admob, inmobi

I am evaluating multiple ad providers for my app and on the process I found that `Admob` (`Google Mobile Ads`) is a best choice since it has integration with multiple providers via mediation. Below are what I have done

1. Integrated the `Google Mobile Ads sdk`
2. Created respective accounts in `Admob`
3. Implemented the controls in `iOS` App
4. Was able to show test ads from `Google` (As my app is still not into store I use test Ads)

Next step was to integrated `InMobi` via Mediation, followed the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/inmobi)

1. Created App in `InMobi`
2. Created `Banner` and `Interstitial` ad placements
3. Created Mediation group in `Admob` and associated `InMobi` as new provider
4. Created an Ad unit in AdMob

Tried to fetch the Ad, as per the documentation `InMobi` is supposed to serve test ads for those apps not in Appstore. But when I tried to fetch the ad **I am getting the below error, any pointers?**

```
2018-08-04 12:55:13.994969+0530 AdsTest[19690:679571] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process AdsTest
    2018-08-04 12:55:13.995239+0530 AdsTest[19690:679571] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
    2018-08-04 12:55:13.995833+0530 AdsTest[19690:679571] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
    adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show.
```